# multiprocessing Manager fails to apply_async from a shared process.pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool, apply-async

I have two daemon processes running.  One feeds data into a shared multiprocessing.Queue, and the other takes data from this Queue and submits it into a multiprocessing.pool.apply_async.  The async result is sent to another multiprocessing.Queue.

Some example code:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
import random
import time


def my_method(i):
    return i*i


class DataFeeder:
    input_queue = None

    @staticmethod
    def stream_to_queue(iq):
        if DataFeeder.input_queue is None:
            DataFeeder.input_queue = iq

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            dat = random.choice(range(0, 50))
            print(f"feeding {dat}")
            DataFeeder.input_queue.put(dat)


class DataEater:
    input_queue = None
    results_queue = None
    pool = None

    @staticmethod
    def eat(iq, rq, p):
        if DataEater.input_queue is None:
            DataEater.input_queue = iq
        if DataEater.results_queue is None:
            DataEater.results_queue = rq
        if DataEater.pool is None:
            DataEater.pool = p

        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            dat = DataEater.input_queue.get(0.1) # 100ms timeout
            print(f"eating {dat}")
            async_result = DataEater.pool.apply_async(my_method, (dat,))
            print(f"async_result {async_result}")
            DataEater.results_queue.put_nowait(async_result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as m:
        input_q = m.Queue()
        output_q = m.Queue()
        pool = m.Pool(8)

        dfp = Process(target=DataFeeder.stream_to_queue, args=(input_q,), daemon=True)
        dfp.start()

        dep = Process(target=DataEater.eat, args=(input_q, output_q, pool), daemon=True)
        dep.start()

        dep.join()
        dfp.join()
```

The resulting stacktrace is as follows:

```
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/integration_tests/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/integration_tests/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/chhunb/PycharmProjects/micromanager_server/umanager_server/multiproctest.py", line 54, in eat
    async_result = DataEater.pool.apply_async(my_method, (dat,))
  File "<string>", line 2, in apply_async
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/integration_tests/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 816, in _callmethod
    proxytype = self._manager._registry[token.typeid][-1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_registry'
```

I've tried spawning the pool locally in the `eat()` method, so that it would spawn from within the new process.  This won't work because the result is an `async_result` and has to be shared with other processes using the `results_queue`.

I've tried completely ignoring the DataFeeder by hard coding some string into the apply-async input.  Same error.

This open python issue is very similar, if not exactly the same as what i'm doing:
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/80100
The issue is still open so does that mean it was never resolved in later versions of python?

Do i have to consider a completely different design pattern to get this functionality?

Comment: The shown code is syntactically incorrect and misses a part mentioned in the traceback. Try to create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Better format the traceback as code.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for the comments.  I edited the code and can reproduce the error.  The stacktrace now reflects the output in my IDE.  I also removed the static initializer since it wasn't needed and the usage shown i think is more the norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a hackish approach which was tested only on Python 3.11 on Windows. It may break for other than the CPython implementation, other Python versions, other OS'

Moreover it currently transfers the authentication key of the manager's server between processes (this is considered unsafe) but this could be changed if necessary with a fixed key.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading

import random
import time


def my_method(i):
    return i*i


class DataFeeder:
    input_queue = None

    @staticmethod
    def stream_to_queue(iq):
        if DataFeeder.input_queue is None:
            DataFeeder.input_queue = iq

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            dat = random.choice(range(0, 50))
            print(f"feeding {dat}")
            DataFeeder.input_queue.put(dat)


class DataEater:
    input_queue = None
    results_queue = None
    pool = None

    @staticmethod
    def eat(iq, rq, p, adr, auth, registry):
        
        if DataEater.input_queue is None:
            DataEater.input_queue = iq
        if DataEater.results_queue is None:
            DataEater.results_queue = rq
        if DataEater.pool is None:
            DataEater.pool = p

        # Here begins the magic (aka dirty hack):
        # Constructing a new manager connected to the same server process
        # as the manager in main thread           
        from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
        
        manager = SyncManager(address=adr, authkey=auth)

        # Updating the registry:

        registry.update(SyncManager._registry)
        SyncManager._registry = registry
        
        manager.connect()
        
        # Setting our manager as manager of the pool proxy
        DataEater.pool._manager = manager

        # Continue normally

        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            dat = DataEater.input_queue.get(0.1) # 100ms timeout
            print(f"eating {dat}")
            async_result = DataEater.pool.apply_async(my_method, (dat,))
            print(f"async_result {async_result}")
            DataEater.results_queue.put_nowait(async_result)


# Additional function/process to wait for the asynchronous result and print it:
def data_printer(output_q):
    while True:
        item = output_q.get()
        result = item.get()
        print(f"awaited async result {result}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as m:
        input_q = m.Queue()
        output_q = m.Queue()
        pool = m.Pool(8)
        
        dpp = Process(target=data_printer, args=(output_q,), daemon=True)
        dpp.start()

        dfp = Process(target=DataFeeder.stream_to_queue, args=(input_q,), daemon=True)
        dfp.start()

        # Three additional arguments added to create a remote manager in the process
        dep = Process(target=DataEater.eat, args=(input_q, output_q, pool, m.address, m._authkey, m._registry), daemon=True)
        dep.start()

        dep.join()
        dfp.join()
        dpp.join()
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much for this.  It works!
I think your solution is clever, even if hacky, but that is necessary.  The link to the github issue suggests this is because the Pool proxy does not contain a manager reference.  If I understand correctly, your solution is basically to give that Pool the manager reference manually!

Comment: And for reference. I tested this on 3.9 mac os and it works.  I'll try it on other systems soon.